# Adding a Custom Form to an Existing List Schema

Tags: 2010, custom-list, custom-form, schema

### Scenario

A list is deployed using the OOB forms. Production data is added. We now need to add a custom form to the list.

The forms are added using this approach:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <!- EditForm is now using TestEdit.aspx -->
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="TestEdit.aspx" Path="testedit.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="FALSE"  />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Source: http://sp2013.blogspot.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-list-custom-form.html
This approach is how I've successfully been adding forms to a newly created list.

The problem is that when an updated list schema is deployed with the new form references, instead of showing the custom form, a blank modal is shown with a disabled Ribbon. When the list is deleted and recreated, the correct form is shown, but we cannot do this because we need to keep the list data.

[image: Missing form modal]

### Troubleshooting

**Schema**
Comparing the schema returned by the [ExportList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587391(v=office.11).aspx) method of the [URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587743(v=office.11).aspx)

TOP: A working list with custom form.
MIDDLE: The broken list.
BOTTOM: An OOB list.

```
<Form Url="Lists/WorkingList/DispForm.aspx" Name="{GUID}" Type="DisplayForm" Default="TRUE" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" FormID="0"/>
<Form Url="Lists/BrokenList/DispForm.aspx" Name="{GUID}" Type="DisplayForm" Default="TRUE" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" FormID="0"/>
<Form Url="Lists/OOBList/DispForm.aspx" Name="{GUID}" Type="DisplayForm" Default="TRUE" FormID="0"/>
```

Because the custom forms recognize the "UseLegacyForm" attribute, I believe the schema was updated with the reference to the custom form. Something else must be going wrong.

**Breakpoint**
Breakpoints in the code behind of the custom form are not hit. Other breakpoints in the solution are. It seems this form is not being touched.

### Not the Solution

These are the things I have already tried.
 1. IISRESET
 2. Deactivating/reactivating the feature.
 3. Recycle app pool.
 4. Using a [rendering template](http://work.eswarprakash.com/2010/12/28/sharepoint-rendering-templates-the-basics/) custom form instead of the approach linked above.

What seems promising is setting the [SPList.DefaultNewFormUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultnewformurl(v=office.15).aspx) property or [SPContentType.NewFormUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.newformurl.aspx) in the feature receiver, but the forms are not rendered properly (example: without a Ribbon).

Comment: Have you tried adding(attaching to the list) these forms using Powershell?

Comment: No. Can you link documentation or an example of this approach?

Comment: You can also use feature activate event http://veenstra.xyz/2011/12/09/updating-custom-forms-on-an-existing-list/

Comment: I see your problem. You're logged in a "System Account"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change my approach to how I was using custom forms so that the form could be attached programatically in a feature receiver. Instead of pointing the list schema to an aspx page with a user control that creates the guts of the form, I pointed it to a Rendering Template. Rendering templates can be set in both the schema and the code. Heres some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544142(v=office.14).aspx) that helped me set this up.